# creating android app shortcut on the home screen

Tags: android, shortcut

I need to add a shortcut for my app on the home screen (programmatically).
I know that the app store do this by default, but for start, the app won't be on the google app store.
I searched a lot, and found basically the same lines of code over and over, and it doesn't seem to work for me.

the code I used:
in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainScreenActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in the onCreate method I called the function that does the following:

```
    private boolean createShortcut()
{
    //create shortcut intent
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainScreenActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    //create intent to add and define the shortcut
    Intent addingIntent = new Intent();
    addingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,shortcutIntent);
    addingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"SenseGuard");
    addingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.peak_detection_icon));
    addingIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addingIntent);
}
```

I tried switching "getApplicationContext()" to "this".
I tried with an actual tablet and on an emulator but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I think this only applies to the AOSP implementation of the launcher. Any custom launcher should be able to decide when or when not to add a shortcut outside of the app drawer.

Comment: @TheWanderer so it's not possible?

Comment: an install from Play Store always adds a shortcut on the next one screen, by default (I believe).

Comment: @MartinZeitler it depends on which launcher you're using. Nova, for instance, has this option off by default.

Comment: @TheWanderer I'd rather wonder, if one can check, if the shortcut already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like This:

**Step 1:**

Update your manifest.xml :

```
  <uses-permission
    android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

**Step 2:**

in your MainActivity.java create **addShortcut()** method and in it`s block put this code :

```
private void addShourcut(){
  Intent shortCutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,MainActivity.class);

  shortCutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

  Intent addIntent = new Intent();

  addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT , shortCutIntent);
  addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME , "Convertor");
  addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE ,
    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext() , R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
  addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
  addIntent.putExtra("duplicate" , false);
  getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

}
```

**Step3:**

set onClickListener for your view that be create shortcut :

```
img_pin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_pin);
img_pin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    addShourcut();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "shortcut created !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
});
```

This is worked for me ...
happy codinngggg...:)

Comment: Thanks! it worked :)
the problem was the permission was wrong.
can you explain what is step 3 for?

Comment: your welcome dear, sure ...if  you have viewed and you want the click of view to create the shortcut, you pass the step3 ... for example, click on  imagView and the shortcut created:)

Answer (score 1):

That code isn't guaranteed to work. That broadcast is also sent by [ShortcutManagerCompat](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/df40ba39ba85fb8629d135bfcd54c1186cf0a4b5/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/pm/ShortcutManagerCompat.java#L89) (which you should probably be using instead of manually sending the broadcast).

However, there are two problems with this.

1. Your default launcher isn't guaranteed to listen for this broadcast. Nova Launcher, for example, has this behavior disabled by default. Other launchers might not even listen for that action at all.
2. On Android Oreo (26) and above, this won't work how you expect it to (read the comments on the method I linked for more details).

You can use this logic still and hope that it works for some of your users, but keep in mind that many default launchers no longer even have app drawers, so adding a shortcut could give your users duplicate icons. Also, I know that, at least for me, I have my home screen organized how I want, and if I install an app, it would be really annoying for it to add itself to my home screen.

If you *are* using the default AOSP launcher (or a close fork), however, and it isn't working, make sure you add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: @Itay in that case, do you have the permission defined?

Comment: my intent was to use the default launcher. I think that for Oreo and above there's a new shortcut implementation. anyway thanks for helping :)